# How to make vs2013 asp.net application look right on mobile?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

vs2013 web forms project.

As I understand, vs2013 uses bootstrap to make website responsive. In the project it has Site.Master and Site.Mobile.Master. I currently added all my menus in Site.Master, I didn't touch Site.Mobile.Master. The web application doesn't look right on mobile phone.

So what should I do to make it right on mobile phone?

Comment: Have you used bootstrap to stylize Master page further ? if yes, it should be fully compatible with mobile devices. have a look [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594098/How-to-customize-Twitter-Bootstrap-to-fit-your-web "How to customize Twitter Bootstrap to fit your web design") which encapsulates custom styles along with bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you. vs2013 is using bootstrap in its project template with Master page,which means I don't need to add my own code. What modification do I need to make it work?

Comment: please have a look in article i suggested above. Rule of thumb is not to touch bootstrap, instead accommodate your custom styles separately. Ideally you use only bootstrap class for layouts, components & bootstrap will take care of responsiveness. For theme(base colors), you will create your styles following practice mentioned in the article.